# post box/bin validation

Tags: regex

I need to provide the P.O Box validation for the address Fields in the registration page. Now we have a regex validation in jquery which has some limitations as follows:

1. If an address polo Rd is given, it identifies "po" in  polo and alerts error message.

So, we should frame a new validation which should not accept address lines with the values:

1. `"PO BOX"`,  `"PO BIN"`,  `"BIN"`, `"P.O BOX"`, `"P.O BIN"`, `"P.O"`, `"PO"`
2. the above values can be in any case
3. spaces before, in between  and after the above words should also be found and validated. For example:  `"    P  O    1234    "`  should be validated and alert error message.
4. But `"Polo Rd"`, `"Robin Rd"`, `"testbintest"` should be accepted as valid address in both the address lines.

The code right now in jquery validation is:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("nopobox", function(value, element) {
   return this.optional(element) || ! /(P(OST)?\.?\s*O(FF(ICE)?)?\.?\s*(?<!(BOX)|(BIN)))|(^[^0-9]*((P(OST)?\.?\s*O(FF(ICE)?)?\.?)|(?<!(BOX)|(BIN))))/i.test(value);
}, "");
```

Comment: Hi Can any one fx this ? please

Answer (score 2):

```
/**
 * The below are the possible combinations P.O.BOX, PO.BOX, P O BOX, P O B O
 * X, POBOX, PO BOX, P.O.B.O.X
 * 
 * @param input
 * @return true if the input value = pobox else false
 */
public static boolean checkPoBox(String input) {
    boolean poBox = false;
    String inputVal = input;
    try {
        if (input.length() > 4) {
            inputVal = inputVal.replace(".", "").replace(" ", "")
                    .toLowerCase();
            if (inputVal.contains("pobox")
                    || inputVal.equalsIgnoreCase("pobox")) {
                poBox = true;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.debug("Exception from checkPoBox");
    }
    return poBox;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution to your problem is that **you need to require a white space** after the initial P.O matching. That way you will not match addresses that start with Po-. Then you also need to cover the case with just a plane BOX or BIN.

Try something along these lines:

/^\s*((P(OST)?.?\s*O(FF(ICE)?)?.?**\s+**(B(IN|OX))?)|B(IN|OX))/i

There are many nice tools to make the design of regular expressions a bit easier to overview. One such tool that you can find online is [RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/).